# How to append module url to an area?

Tags: module, admin, routing

So I have a module (Menu) that I built following a tutorial and I want to treat it as an area. I then want to build other modules (I have Magento's Hello World module currently integrated for testing) but I haven't been able to find anywhere how I can append hello world to my menu url?

e.g. the url for hello world is: `/admin/helloworld/hello/index/`
what I would like is something like `/admin/myMenuFrontName/helloworld/hello/index/`

but I'm not sure where to even begin. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is actually really easy when I gave it more thought:

You have a menu module to control menu links. Then you have an area-based module, e.g. helloworld

Then inside that you have folders per sub-module controller. E.g. the file tree should be something like:

```
Company
|----Module
|--------Menu
|--------HelloWorld
|------------Controller
|----------------Adminhtml
|--------------------Area1
|------------------------Index.php
|--------------------Area2
|------------------------Index.php
```

along with all the other files. Then set up routing like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route id="helloworld" frontName="helloworld">
            <module name="Company_HelloWorld" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

then after that you can have `helloworld/area1/index` and so on